# Google map not displaying some landmarks in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I am new to android and working on an application which display `Google map`. So I followed the steps for loading google map in my application and it worked successfully but the map shown in my app is not displaying some of the landmarks, which are usually displayed in Google map app.

> For more explanation, the map in my application is displaying college
>   library, main driveway, Children’s Park near my location but it is not
>   displaying the college name,or similarly it is displaying street
>   numbers and road names but not displaying any of the restaurants,bars
>   or any business landmarks.

The xml code:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"        
  android:layout_width="match_parent"        
  android:layout_height="match_parent"        
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

The java code :

```
package com.example.mapprototype;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
 }
}
```

Google play service and google map api key are added in manifest file.

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="my_api_key"/>
```

Do I need to add something else to display all the landmarks like **bars,restaurant,colleges etc.** that are displayed in google map default application .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such minor details are not included in the Google Maps API.

However you can fetch nearby places using the Places API and make your own markers on the map.

**Further readings:**

[Google Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) 
[Usage example by Tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-displaying-places-of-interest--mobile-16145)